# Counting up 0 to 100

Tags: java, android

CountDown 0 to 100 Android
I'm only beginner with android can you help me guys with this.
The Result must be the end of the countdown.
for example, the result value is 75 the countdown will start to 0 ends to 75

```
 mCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult();
            new CountDownTimer(30000, 100){
               public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                  waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(counter);
                  waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.format("%d%%",result)); //result is the value from randomize 60 to 80 .

                    result++;
                }
                public  void onFinish(){
                }
            }.start();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// result varible define as a public
    long result = 80;
    mCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(result * 1000, 100) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // its start with 1 if you want start with 0 then replace with below code
                    //int sec = (int) (result - (millisUntilFinished / 1000)-1);
                    int sec = (int) (result - (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                    waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(sec);
                    waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.valueOf(result)); //result is the value from randomize 60 to 80 .

                }

                public void onFinish() {
                }
            }.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: the "result" is integer

Comment: it is working but its to slow in counting even I change the countdown interval

Comment: It is 1 second  countdown.

Comment: its ok now i changed  new CountDownTimer(result *50, 500)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 mCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showResult();
            new CountDownTimer(result*1000, 1000){
               public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                  waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(counter);
                  waveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.format("%d%%",newResult)); //newResult is temp value initialize with 0

                    newResult++; 
                }
                public  void onFinish(){
                }
            }.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry i change the question above 

The Result must be the end of the countdown.
for example, the result value is 75 the countdown will start to 0 ends to 75

Comment: its to slow to count why

Comment: Its taking 1 second as interval

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the matching parameters when instantiating the [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for your use case, take a look for CountDownTimer constructor method [`CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long,%20long)). When you want to create a count down from 0 to 100 with 1 second step, you can construct your code like this:

```
final long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
final long ONE_HUNDRED_SECOND = 100 * ONE_SECOND;

new CountDownTimer(ONE_HUNDRED_SECOND, ONE_SECOND){
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      int second = millisUntilFinished / ONE_SECOND;

      int counter = second - 1;

      // do something with the counter value

    }
    public  void onFinish() {
      // do something when we finished the count down.
    }
}.start();
```